# /usr/bin/ar: libsql_main.a: No space left on device

Tags: linux, filesystems, ar

I need to install libmysqlclient. Unfortunately, this package is no longer in the "main" Arch Linux repository and it has been moved to AUR, so I have to compile it myself. During compilation I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/ar: libsql_main.a: No space left on device
```

This message does not have to be identical to the English version. I tried to translate it as best as possible, but here's original message:

```
/usr/bin/ar: libsql_main.a: Brak miejsca na urządzeniu
```

I certainly don't lack disk space. I don't think any library weighs 50 GB? Maybe it was RAM? I have 8 GB RAM and 8 GB swap. I don't think it weighs over 16 GB... What else does linker need?

Look. Here's output of `df -h` command:

```
System plików                  rozm. użyte dost. %uż. zamont. na
dev                             3,8G     0  3,8G   0% /dev
run                             3,8G  1,7M  3,8G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/cryptvolgroup-root  166G  115G   43G  73% /
tmpfs                           3,8G   68M  3,7G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs                           3,8G     0  3,8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                        53G   46G  7,3G  87% /windows
tmpfs                           3,8G  3,6G  165M  96% /tmp
/dev/loop0                      172M  172M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/skype/123
/dev/loop1                      175M  175M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/skype/118
/dev/loop2                       94M   94M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/core/9066
/dev/loop3                       94M   94M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/core/8935
/dev/loop4                      125M  125M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/scratux/6
/dev/loop5                       55M   55M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/core18/1705
/dev/loop6                      161M  161M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/gnome-3-28-1804/116
/dev/loop7                       63M   63M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/gtk-common-themes/1506
/dev/loop8                       55M   55M     0 100% /var/lib/snapd/snap/core18/1754
/dev/loop9                      428M  428M     0 100% /var/lib/anbox/rootfs
tmpfs                           767M  148K  767M   1% /run/user/1000
```

Here's my fstab:

```
# Static information about the filesystems.
# See fstab(5) for details.

# <file system> <dir> <type> <options> <dump> <pass>
# /dev/mapper/cryptvolgroup-root
UUID=<nice uuid>    /           ext4        rw,relatime 0 1

# /dev/mapper/cryptvolgroup-swap
UUID=<nice uuid>    none        swap        defaults    0 0

# windows
UUID=<nice uuid>    /windows/   ntfs        rw,realtime 0 1
```

What causes this error?

Comment: My guess is it's trying to write something rather large to `/tmp/` and failing. Free some space there and try again

Comment: There are only two non-empty folders in /tmp/: `1,2M v8-compile-cache-1000`,
`3,6G yaourt-tmp-notroot`

Comment: So? Accoding to your `df` output, it's still 96% full.

Comment: But all this space is filled with files I'm trying to compile...

Comment: Then move them somewhere else with more space.

Comment: I specified build directory to yaourt with `--tmp` option. I don't know if it will work because the program compiles extremely slowly and it will take a long time before it reaches 53% where this error occured.

Comment: Compilers use /tmp as work area. Your /tmp is in RAM, free RAM or half of it, which one is lower. If that is a developing machine, consider moving /tmp to disk, for instance, under /, which has 43GB free.

Comment: I compiled it and it works.